# get element from ArrayList (java)

Tags: java, arraylist

Struggling with what is probably a simple query to match and return an element in an `ArrayList`.

I first store a `HashSet` in the `ArrayList` because `HashSet` has no get method and then check the `ArrayList` (which contains the correct elements, strings of socket references).

```
List theseSocks = new ArrayList(NodeConnMaster.sockList);

System.out.println("array list contains " + theseSocks);
```

I then want to iterate through and find the matching ipAddress in the element and once found set a variable to the entire element, so something like -

```
for (int i =0; i<  theseSocks.size(); i++) {
   if (theseSocks.toString().contains(ipAddress)) {
       int element = theseSocks.get();
       System.out.println("the element is " + element);
   }
}
```

but it appears that get needs an index position and I am trying to get based on string contents, not index.

Is there an easier way than deleting all the elements except the matching one and then returning index `0`.

Or is `ArrayList` not the way to go.

The solution was, with SBylemans's help  -

```
Object currentSock = null;     
for (int i =0; i<  theseSocks.size(); i++)
{
currentSock = theseSocks.get(i);
if (currentSock.toString().contains(ipAddress))
    {
    System.out.println("the element is " +currentSock);
    break;
    }
}
```

Regards
Ralph

Comment: Assuming the HashSet elements are of type String: String matchingElement = NodeConnMaster.sockList.stream().filter(element -> element.contains(ipAddress)).findAny().orElse(null);

Comment: `Collection.removeIf(Predicate)`.

Comment: Thanks Selaron, but is there an equivalent for lambda expressions  for Java 6? Jai, please elaborate (please show me how I would use in my if and then get)

Comment: **if** this question is for Java 6 (only) you should include that tag (and eventually mention it in the question) - actual Version is 11!

Comment: None of the following solutions will work if it is Java 6. What you are lacking is that `theseSocks.get()` should be `theseSocks.get(i)`, though you may need to shuffle the codes a little bit. I'm fairly sure you don't need `contains()` - you probably need `equals()`.

Comment: Apologies, but help still required.

Comment: What type is `theseSocks`? A list of lists? A list of strings? We can't know when you are using raw type.

Comment: theseSocks are TCP sockets as defined when using socket s = new Socket

Comment: Let's assume the follwiing should return an element from `theseSocks`: `int element = theseSocks.get();` - Why is `element` of type `int` and not `Socket`?

Comment: Object cannot be converted to Socket (ArrayList contains objects, those objects are Socket strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping over the ArrayList and want to compare based on the String value. But looping like this will immediately also give you the index. Your loop should look something like this:

```
for (int i =0; i<  theseSocks.size(); i++)
{
   String currentSock = theseSocks.get(i);
   if (currentSock.equals(ipAddress))
   {
       System.out.println("the element is " +currentSock);
       break;
   }
}
```

Or even with a `forEach` loop

```
for (String currentSock: theseSocks)
{
   if (currentSock.equals(ipAddress))
   {
       System.out.println("the element is " +currentSock);
       break;
   }
}
```

The `break` is used to interupt the for loop once your element is found.

Additionaly, your `if` condition will cause a print of every element if the array contains the ipAddress you're looking for.

**Edit** And then when using java 8, you can also use streams as posted by others.

Comment: Thanks SBylemans, though 'cant find symbol TheseSocksObject', do I have to initialize first?  The object being stored is a complete TCP socket reference (IP address, port an local IP port being bound)

Comment: @Ralph as said, I used `TheseSocksObject ` because it is not clear from your question which object is stored in the ArrayList. Which objects are in the HashSet? Use that class instead of `TheseSocksObject`. Probably the `Socket` class I guess?

Comment: the HashSet and the ArrayList contain objects, those objects are TCP strings created when using Socket s = new Socket (HashSet and ArrayList are objects / elements, they cannot be converted 'back' to sockets, I just want to display the matched one)

Comment: @Ralph Ok, so you can replace `TheseSocksObject` by `String`. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks, eventually used an object and now have a working query (edited my original post if useful to anyone else).

Answer (score 3):

You can use stream of Java8 for filtering required elements like:

```
List wantedList = theseSocks.stream()
.filter(e ->e.toString().contains(ipAddress))
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```